# The reaction mechanism for epoxides to react with LiAlH4

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

Does anyone know the mechanism for the reaction of epoxides with Lithium aluminium hydride (product of course being an alcohol)

Comment: Depends how precise.

Comment: I suspect that this paper will go a long way to answering your query, but as it is behind a paywall I cannot be sure  https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01038a042

Comment: I'm experiencing paywall problems